# Is there a way to prefetch the timeline?

Tags: timeline

In the motion tracking part of blender you can prefetch your video to make it play smoothly, is there a way to do that with the regular timeline so if I have a scene at 60 FPS, I can play it at 60 FPS instead of it playing at like 5 or 10 FPS?

Comment: If you are doing something with cloth or rigidbody etc you can bake the results.  This means you precalculate and store the scene arrangement per frame.  For things like procedural mesh deformation, this usually has to happen on the fly.

Comment: Ok thank you. I know how to bake, but I wasn't sure if you could do what you do in after effects where if you play the timeline once, it goes green and you can play it again and it goes smoothly.